# Magento Admin Backend Blank Page after login

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have a serious problem in Magento Admin Backend. After login its shows a BLANK Page. i used the same files and database in different server, there it was working fine but when i have transferred files into LIVE then Admin issues came. Please help me over this as i got frustrated from last some dayz. If you need any more dertails then plz ask but i need to resolve this soon. Link: http://studywings.com/index.php/admin/
Magento ver: 1.7

Answer (score 3):

flush your magento root /var/cache folder and /var/session folders, It may have previous server session that may cause problems.
Otherwise disable all third party modules and try again. I think this will help

Comment: Thankz Rehan, for your response.. but i did these all steps but still not resolved. Can u plz help me, how to disable third party modules without Admin Panel?

Comment: in magento installation folder goto app/etc/modules/ and just rename all xml files which are not starting with "Mage_" and one that name "Phoenix_Moneybookers"

Comment: renamed, but still not resolved :( after clicking LOGIN button, it stopped redirecting. If you need i will provide you the username and password. plz help me..

Answer (score 2):

I had the Same problem,

i have also debug the any errors occured, i tried index.php file

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
```

pleced above code in index.php file. after that i have tried admin login.

showing the errors are session related, header already send errors.

i have to add the code in root/index.php file in top add the following line.

```
ob_start();
```

after that tried the login its worked.

Cheers..!

Answer (score 1):

Is url changes to this after click login button or not?

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/index/index/key/(key value)/
```

if url changes but not not show the dashboard page then go to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

make copy of this file

Find the code for setting session cookie parameters these started on line 77
Comment out the final three lines and be sure to remove the comma after `$this->getCookie()->getPath()`. You should end up with this:

```
// set session cookie params 
session_set_cookie_params( 
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(), 
$this->getCookie()->getPath() 
// $this->getCookie()->getDomain(), 
// $this->getCookie()->isSecure(), 
// $this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
```

also line 104 comment out :

```
//call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

If there is no change in url after click login then try to uncomment display error and see error_log file of your server

Comment: Hi Rehan, the URL is not changing after clicking login button only it become blank page. i have uncommented the display error but still no error are displaying. if you need i can provide you the ftp details, i m totly confused what to do. Plz help me Rehan.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is due to file permissions. As you added files from one server to another, permissions might be get changed.. Try to give the permissions to all the files. Check this http://www.mage-shop.com/forum/threads/3-Magento-Admin-Backend-Blank-Page-Error

Comment: Thankz John, i will check this and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things that can cause it, but it's most common after migrating to a new server, last time it happened to me it was an excessively low php memory_limit setting on the new server - the Admin part of the site uses a lot more resources per user than the frontend.

In general when having this issue:

- Flush out your cache by emptying `var/cache`
- Clear out sessions by emptying `var/sessions`
- Check the magento error logs/reports for an error code in `var\logs` and `var/reports`
- Turn on magento error logs in mysql if logging isn't already on! (look in core_config_data for `WHERE path like 'dev/log/active'`
- Check if your php configuration is displaying errors
- Check your apache/php error logs for more clues - memory errors will show up here for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

It sounds like you want to enable Developer mode. Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

You may also want to enable display errors in index.php:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

The best way I have found to debug is with X-Debug in a local environment. You can also use log files to help debug in a production environment, if your unable to run X-Debug in the environment.

I've got a more detailed posting here:

http://www.molotovbliss.com/debugging-tips-and-tricks-with-magento-commerce

Consider also installing [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the other answers....

I am upgrading a magento install, and got the same problem, in the end I had another folder inside of var/

magento/var/minifycache

Only worked after clear deleting the files inside of this folder.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after uninstalling an extension. I thought that clearing cache would be enough, and I did without success... later speaking with the technical team, they commented me that it did not work because I hace memcache installed, and needed to be done the cleaning via system - backend (that i coudl not see...)